# CPT search using meta_query and meta key as array

Tags: meta-query

Hi i got custom post type and meta key 'tf_elements' which is an array and look like this:

```
a:28:{s:22:"Mikrofon bezprzewodowy";s:3:"Tak";s:19:"Mikrofon przewodowy";s:3:"Tak";s:39:"Sprzęt do tłumaczenia symultanicznego";s:3:"Tak";s:10:"Magnetofon";s:3:"Tak";s:13:"Odtwarzacz CD";s:3:"Tak";s:5:"Scena";N;s:8:"Mównica";N;s:12:"Zaciemnienie";N;s:12:"Klimatyzacja";N;s:17:"Światło dzienne";N;s:19:"Obsługa techniczna";N;s:29:"Business centre + sekretariat";N;s:21:"Minibar konferencyjny";N;s:21:"Rzutnik multimedialny";N;s:13:"Rzutnik folii";N;s:16:"Rzutnik slajdów";N;s:15:"Magnetowid i TV";N;s:5:"Ekran";N;s:9:"Flipchart";N;s:6:"Kamera";N;s:21:"Tablica suchościerna";N;s:18:"Wskaźnik laserowy";N;s:8:"Komputer";N;s:16:"Wideokonferencje";N;s:7:"Telefon";N;s:3:"Fax";N;s:19:"Łącze internetowe";N;s:26:"Wi-Fi (bezprzew. internet)";N;}
```

I got search box on page with multiply checkboxes and i want to check search thru this array for example i check two options:

Mikrofon Bezprzewodowy = "TAK" AND
Miktofon przewodowy = "TAK" AND ETC.

Is there any simple way to accomplish that ?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: "Is there any simple way to accomplish that ?" -- No. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+serialized